# building python packages on one linux distro and running them from another

Tags: python, linux, scientific-computing

Is it problematic to build python packages (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, h5py,...)  on one linux distro (ubuntu) and run them from another distro (centos)?
I am asking this because our computing cluster has centos machines while my pc is ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any problem if you change the way of packaging. Ubuntu needs a different type of packaging while centos needs another type. Build your package and pack it in such a way as normal centos packages and then use it in centos

Answer (score 0):

Use distutils to package as eggs and specify the dependencies you should not have too many problems - the pyo files that are zipped into the eggs work fine across platforms.  You might like to take a look at pypiserver to set up a local pypi that you can pip from.